# This code works everywhere but Firefox for Mac

Tags: wordpress, facebook, macos, firefox

This code which I'm using to import a news feed from a Facebook page into Wordpress recently stopped working, but only in Firefox for Mac:

```
<iframe style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 740px; height: 1200px; background: white; float: left;" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FPageNameHere&amp;width=740&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;height=1200" width="300" height="150" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

Seems to work in Firefox on PC.  I'm not sure when it stopped working on Firefox for Mac, but I believe it originally worked.  Now it's simply blank on the page.

Comment: When you inspect your page do you have some errors? Can you pinpoint the iframe to see if there is a content loaded inside?

Comment: Do you have an example url where this is happening?